# How can I view .JSP files

Tags: jsp

I am new with web application and I have some files (web files) with the extension of `.jsp`. I would like to know how I can view them in suitble way in my machine? Do I need apache server?

**Note:** I am talking about the end-user view NOT the programmer view!

Comment: I want to see the user-end view NOT the code!

Comment: :Den y ur question says "open .jsp"????

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Install Apache on your PC. Put the JSP file in the /htdocs/JSP folder in the Apache installation. You will have to create the JSP folder. Name the JSP file index.jsp. Open Apache and start the web service (the top one. Click Start)
To view it, go to your browser and type in the following URL: 127.0.0.1/JSP. If that doesn't work, type in 127.0.0.1/JSP/index.jsp

This should help.

Answer (score 4):

JSP files are JavaServer Pages, and you'll need to run a JSP server to have them run. If you have Apache installed, you'll be able to get the jsp application running with Apache Tomcat: http://tomcat.apache.org .

Answer (score 3):

Basically to open a `.jsp` file, you can use `notepad`, `notepad++`, `eclipse`, `textpad` and so on.

To open whole application, debug, run and test, better to use `Eclipse`.

Answer (score 1):

Download JRun From Adobe
http://www.adobe.com/products/jrun/

I still use JRun though.

You could also make use of Eclipse.
http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/moreinfo/jee.php

Comment: JRun?   Seriously?  That's been dead for at least 5 years.

Comment: driving a nail with a tractor bucket..?

Answer (score 1):

open the application in notepad or any other IDE you like, or you can open it on any browser it shows code there, copy the whole code then paste it in a new text doc and save it as HTML (with the extension .html) you are good to go, hope you like the easy solution.

Answer (score 0):

Open it with a standard text editor to see what is written inside (for instance notepad, editpad or any other you like).

Actually "A JSP is an HTML page containing a reference to Java servlets, or,  java server side applets. " as said [here](http://whatis.techtarget.com/file-extension/JSP-FileFormat.html)